# Is there an irreducible, noncompact commuting, nonnormal operator, with spectrum strictly continuous?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

**Definition**: The **commutant** $\mathcal{S}'$ of a subset $\mathcal{S} \subset B(H)$ is $ \{A \in B(H) : AB=BA \ , \ \forall B \in \mathcal{S}  \} $.

**Definitions** : An operator $A \in B(H)$ is :

- **Irreducible** ([Halmos 1968](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Irreducible-operators/10.1307/mmj/1028999975.full)) if its commutant $\{ A\}'$ does not contain projections other than $0$ and $I$ ($A \ne A_{1} \oplus A_{2}$, $A$ generates $B(H)$ as von Neumann algebra : $\{A,A^{*}\}''=B(H)$).
- **Nonnormal** if $\{ A\}'$ does not contain $A^{*}$  (i.e. $AA^{*} \ne A^{*}A$).
- **Noncompact commuting** if $\{ A\}'$ does not contain a compact operator.

**Definition** : The **spectrum** $\sigma(A)$ of $A \in B(H)$ is  $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \text{ not bijective} \}$.
It [decomposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)) as follows:

- *Point spectrum*: $\sigma_{p}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \text{ not injective}   \}$
- *Continuous spectrum*: $\sigma_{c}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{injective, dense nonclosed range}   \}$
- *Residual spectrum*: $\sigma_{r}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{ injective, nondense range}   \}$

The spectrum of $A$ is **strictly continuous** if $\sigma(A) = \sigma_{c}(A)$.

**Examples**:

- Let $S$ be the **bilateral shift** defined on $H = l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ by $S.e_{n} = e_{n+1} $.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* :   $\sigma(S) = \sigma_{c}(S) = \mathbb{S}^{1}$.
  It's also a unitary operator ($SS^{*} = S^{*}S = I$), so a fortiori a *normal* operator.
  It is *noncompact commuting* and *reducible*.
- Let $T$ be the **unilateral shift** defined on $H = l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ by $T.e_{n} = e_{n+1} $.
  Its spectrum is not *strictly continuous* because $0 \in \sigma_{r}(T)$.
  It's a *nonnormal* operator because $[T^{*},T].e_{0} = e_{0}$.
  It is *noncompact commuting* and *irreducible*.
- Let $V$ the **[Volterra operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator)** defined on $H= L^{2}[0,1]$ by $(V.f)(t)=\int_0^tf(x)dx$.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* $\sigma(V) = \sigma_{c}(V) = \{ 0\}$.
  It is *compact*, *irreducible* and *nonnormal* (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446466/is-there-a-nonnormal-operator-with-spectrum-strictly-continuous/)).
- Let $p$ be a non-constant polynomial (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447278/does-the-nontrivial-commutants-of-the-volterra-operator-admit-a-strictly-continu/)).
  Then $p(V)$ is *nonnormal*, *compact commuting* and *irreducible*.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* $\sigma(p(V)) = \sigma_{c}(p(V)) = \{ p(0)\}$.
  It's *compact commuting*, *nonnormal* and *irreducible*.
- Let $S \oplus V$ defined on $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}) \oplus L^{2}[0,1]$.
  It is *reducible*, *compact commuting*, *nonnormal* and with spectrum *strictly continuous*.

*If you find a mistake, thank you let me know in comment.*

> **The main question**: Is there an irreducible, noncompact commuting and nonnormal operator, with spectrum strictly continuous ?

**Bonus questions** : How classify these operators ?

Comment: One more possible example (though not an answer to your question): I think that if you take any non-zero element of the von Neumann algebra of a discrete group $\Gamma$, thought of as an operator on $\ell^2(\Gamma)$, then I *think* you get noncompact commuting and strictly continuous spectrum, and clearly you can arrange for non-normal. But irreducibility is not clear to me right now

Comment: @YemonChoi : Thank you for this comment. What's not clear with irreducibility ? If the group $\Gamma$ is ICC ([infinite conjugacy classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_conjugacy_class_property)), it generates a $II_{1}$ factor, and there are plenty of projections in its commutant, so there is no irreducibility for a single element. Next, for any discrete group $\Gamma$, if we take an irreducible representation $H$, the von Neumann algebra it generates is the whole $B(H)$.

Comment: Could the "downvoter" and "closer" indicate what's wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: [Cross-posted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/448620/38053). Hi Sébastien, you are supposed to let people know when you ask the same question on both sites.

Comment: Hi Julien, I did not know, thank you for this information. I hesitated between the two. I have posted it on MO first, and then on MSE. Where do you think is best for it ?

Comment: Definitely a question for MO.  Don't cross post unless you say so and give the URL for the other post.

Comment: It's ok @BillJohnson, thank you for the exhortation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially I think weighted shifts should be a sufficiently rich class of operators. Consider, for instance, the following example.

Take the doubly infinite sequence
$$ w_k=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 2 & \text{if } k<0 \\ 1 & \text{if } k\geq 0 \end{array}\right. $$
and let $W$ be the weighted shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ defined by
$$ We_j=w_je_{j+1} \qquad \forall j\in\mathbb{Z}\qquad (\text{here }(e_j)\text{ is the usual basis}).$$
Then

1. W has strictly continuous spectrum. This is an almost identical argument the usual bilateral shift.
2. W is not normal. The adjoint is given by $W^\ast e_j=w_{j-1}e_{j-1}$ and so $$W^\ast We_j=w_j^2e_{j},\quad \text{but}\quad WW^\ast e_j = w_{j-1}^2e_j.$$
3. $W$ is irreducible. This follows from Corollary 2 of
   R. Gellar, *Operators commuting with a weighted shift*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **23** (1969), 538-545.
4. <s>I do not seem to be able to show</s> $W$ is non-compact-commuting. See Bill's comment below.

Comment: It is non-compact-commuting. First,  $\|Wx\| \ge \|x\|$, so if $S$ is compact and $S e_n \not= 0$ then $\|W^k S e_n\|$ is bounded away from zero.  However, $(W_k e_n)_k$ tends weakly to zero, so $ (SW_k e_n)_k$ tends in norm to zero.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would've taken me a while to think of something so slick!